# Deja-dup keeps asking me for my password every few minutes and doesn't seem to be doing anything

Tags: xubuntu, backup, deja-dup

Every time I run deja-dup it repeatedly asks me for my password every few mintues. Also, in the 'detals' screen it just shows the same files and doesn't seem to scan any new ones. Any thoughts or ideas? I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: This one helped for me : http://askubuntu.com/questions/462085/deja-dup-repeatedly-asks-encryption-password/508228#508228?newreg=69698b27b6f74a628cd1ec160c20d9f5

Answer (score 0):

I have already encountered this problem (in Ubuntu). I solved it by deleting all the files of the last backup. This solution does not work in all case hope it may help you.