# How to change backup encryption password needed repeatedly, not just once

Tags: password, backup

Is there a way to change repeated requests for a password when 16.04 does back ups? It's a pain to keep hitting continue as the back up scans files while preparing the backup. There's no good reason to prompt for an encryption password repeatedly during a backup after the first prompt for a password. It slows the back up process down substantially, and requires that the user remain at the computer for the hours it takes to back up.

Comment: What tool are you using to do your backups?

Comment: The app that came loaded on my machine. It's just a Linux back up, not to an external drive.

Comment: This started for me today on focal (20.04) for no reason. The tool is Deja-Dup so this seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/462085/138105)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deja-dup repeatedly asks encryption password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462085/deja-dup-repeatedly-asks-encryption-password)